# workflow foundation 4.0 load workflow with arguments

Tags: parameters, load, workflow-foundation

**WF 4.0 with SP1**

We are trying to load workflow and do state traversal based on users actions. So say when user say approve we pass something like below:

```
var activity = new StateMachineApprovalFlow();
        WorkflowApplication application = new WorkflowApplication(activity);
        var approval = new Approval();
        approval.Status = ApprovalStatus.Completed;
        activity.Approval = approval;

        SetupInstanceStore();
        application.InstanceStore = store;

        application.Extensions.Add(new OracleTrackingParticipant());

        application.Load(instanceId);
```

This breaks.First is this the right way or should i use bookmark. i am very new to workflow so example will help.

Thanks

Comment: My work flow is very simple with 3 states in single activity.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create an activity which creates a bookmark.  Then you must run the workflow until it becomes idle waiting for that bookmark.

Then, you load the workflow as you have done and follow that by

```
var result = application.ResumeBookmark(bookmarkName, data);
```

Be sure to check the result to see that it resumed ok.  Microsoft.Activities (available on CodePlex) has some extension methods to make this easier as well.  For a sample see [Microsoft.Activ​ities.UnitTesti​ng - How do I test an activity with bookmarks?](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MicrosoftActivitiesUnitTest-680bf54b)

Comment: Thanks, that's the correct answer i can say as i implemented same yesterday and it worked. By creating NativeActivity, which creates bookmark and than Load work flow and say resume bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

This way of passing parameters only works if your Approvals is an immutable type. Using a Dictionary works with all input types. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560894.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Hi, This link works well for creating WorkflowApplication object in .Net 4.0. but when we are loading we can't pass arguments. So i need other ways to do this